# Is it possible to have two session management strategies for different apis based on ant matcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I was trying out the following config code, to get different session management for two APIs based on ant matchers

```java
 http
 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/apiV1/**").authenticated()
 .and().sessionManagement()
 .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)

 // How to add in details for custom session cookie for apiV1 ?
 .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/apiV2/**").authenticated()
 .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)

 // How to add in details for custom session cookie for apiV2 ?
 .and().oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

I would also require to invalidate `/apiV2` session after 3 minutes (configurable).

Also is it possible to maintain two different session cookie attributes (with custom names) for these two APIs and have code to invalidate them based on some business logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having separate filter chains to handle each request.
Implement 2 separate config classes that extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
Have one with: 
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(""/apiV1/**"")
    .... //
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatcher(""/apiV2/**"")
    ....
```

Spring will create 2 seperate filter chains, and the Filter chain proxy will route requests to each one based on the request matcher, then you can customize the Session fitlers etc in each one, and even have different authentication etc.

More info in this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried this. My issue is that both the request arise from the same browser, and hence would result in the same session Id. Any way to tackle that ?